How Do I Install bundler and jekyll?
I have ruby installed and tried installing bundler jekyll but nothing is downloading
I've tried running gem install bundler jekyll and just gem install bundler jekyll in vs code terminal and my computers terminal idk what to do now

When you ran gem install bundler jekyll what was the output in the terminal?

What OS are you using? e.g. Linux, Windows, Mac?

Jekyll has native extensions as dependencies. Building native extensions requires installed ruby headers. On Ubuntu or Debian, you can install them by running
sudo apt install ruby-dev

If you are using a different OS (such as Windows or Mac OS), you will need a different command.
After the ruby headers are installed, you should be able to gem install jekyll and watch it build the native extensions.
